# Flexslider 2, 2 rows

Tags: html, css, flexslider

so I want flexslider to go on 2 rows, but only one set of " next slide " buttons.

ex. You have 12 childpages, you want them as thumbnail links ( done ), and then I'd want to put those thumb links to a 2 row flexslider, how could this be done?

2 rows, 1 set of buttons.

How could that be done?